# TWCC Delay-Based Estimation with GCC

Tags: webrtc, rtp

I've been learning about Google Congestion Control and how it gathers data from the network. Im looking to confirm my understanding of how `t(i) - t(i-1)` delays are useful.

My comprehension is that the sender stamps each packet with a timestamp (so called, `abs-send-time`). This timestamp is based on the clock of the sender. As packets are transmitted to the receiver, the receiver aims to calculate the 'change' in the delay between the packets it receives.

Presumably this change in latency helps infer when routers are buffering packets, leading to network congestion. The GCC algorithm can then reduce the bitrate to accommodate before packets are eventually lost to the buffers dropping them.

My question is, how does the receiver accurately measure the change in the delay between packets? I understand how one-way delay is tricky, as clocks are not synchronized. Therefore, SR/RR use RTT to estimate two-way delay.

So, the sender stamps each packet with an `abs-send-time`, which are sent at some interval. That interval should be captured in the `abs-send-time` timestamps.

Example:

```
packet_1 abs-send-time = 2022-01-01: 00: 00 : 00 : 000
delay of 10 ms (so called sender_delay_1)
packet_2 abs-send-time = 2022-01-01: 00: 00 : 00 : 010
delay of 10 ms (so called sender_delay_2)
packet_3 abs-send-time = 2022-01-01: 00: 00 : 00 : 020
```

We can infer as the receiver that the send interval was every 10 milliseconds. Now, **if the receive interval isn't every 10 ms**, the receiver knows that **something in the network stopped the packets from being received every 10 ms**.

If `receiver_delay_1` on the receive side is 10 ms, and `receiver_delay_2` is 20 ms, you know that despite being sent at 10 ms intervals, `receiver_delay_2` indicates that the third packet took 10 ms longer than its expected receive interval should be (based on the interval that they were sent at (inferred by the `abs-send-time`).

To summarize:

`abs-send-time` informs the receiver of what the send rate was. The receiver can then use that information to measure against the receive rate of the packets. When they're equal, everything is fine. When there is a delta between the receive rate and the send rate, this can infer that the path is becoming congested as delays in routers will increase the delta between packet receive rates.

Is this a correct understanding here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing concepts from transport-wide-cc and abs-send-time which is used for the older REMB. Both use the same concepts from https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-rmcat-gcc-02 though and it is complicated :-)

In a nutshell you're correct. Absolute clocks can not be assumed between sender and receiver. This is made worse by the fact that typically the high-resolution steady clock is counting time ticks since the machine started. But the time differences expressed in the senders and receivers local time can be compared (assuming the clocks run at the same rate but relativistic effects don't need to be taken into account)

In the case of abs-send-time and REMB the receiver calculates the differences (interarrival deltas) and, taking into account the abs-send-time header extension (which is higher resolution than the RTP timestamp) and then estimates the bitrate.

For transport-wide congestion control the sender tags each packet with a sequence number (transport-wide so the RTP ones can not be used) and stores the send time. The receiver sends feedback consisting of the receive time (in its own clock) and (transport-wide) sequence number. The sender then calculates the delta and estimates whether the delay increases. This goes into the the senders bitrate estimation algorithm.

Comment: Hey Philipp. To make sure I get the difference here: What I described where the `abs-send-time` is what it is used by the receiver is Receiver Estimated Maximum Bitrate estimation. Which now makes sense since that is literally what it is doing haha. For TWCC, the sender mints a packet, attaching a sequencing number and storing its send time (not sending it). Thus the sequence number will be mapped to the send time. The receiver then sends a feedback packet with the same sequence number, and its received timestamp. From here, the sender can compare the receive deltas on the receive side.

Comment: That means that the sender knows the rate at which it transmitted its packets, and now also knows the rate at which the receiver received the packets. Is the difference here that all of the calculations happen at the 'original' sender side? The ID you mention I assume is the sequence number? Now that the sender knows the send rate and the receive rate, it can calculate the differences using the sequence numbers and can therefore infer changes in rates (send vs receive rate). What is the advantage here over REMB?

Comment: correct (and edited the ambiguous "id" above).
The main difference is where the logic is. In REMB, the estimation is done at the receiver side and the result is told to the sender which then changes its bitrate. Tuning such a system needs to be done on both endpoints.
In twcc/send-side bwe the estimation happens in the entity that also encodes (and has more context) while the receiver is "simple". Tuning such a system can happen at the sender.
For example Google Stadia used a different BBR-based estimator at one point https://youtu.be/avtlQeaxd_I?t=800 with no changes to Chrome required.

Comment: Right on Philipp, that makes sense. I’ll check out the link! Thanks a ton as always.